# Dúvidas sobre Vagrant

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, yii, vagrant

Estou aprendendo a trabalhar com o [vagrant](/questions/tagged/vagrant), já criei a `VirtualMachine`, fiz os provisionamentos, o projeto rodou perfeitamente.

Mas quando entro via [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) na `VirtualMachine` para rodar um script [php](/questions/tagged/php), que roda via shell, está apresentando erro de conexão com o [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

> "cdbconnection failed to open the db connection: could not find driver"

Utilizo o framework [yii](/questions/tagged/yii). Outra coisa é quando rodo o vagrant reload perco o acesso ao servidor web remotamente.

Comment: Pode postar a mensagem de erro do mysql?

Comment: Apresenta esta mensagem "cdbconnection failed to open the db connection"

Utilizo o framework yii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mensagem de erro é clara: o driver de acesso ao banco de dados MySQL não foi encontrado.

Provavelmente a extensão não foi habilitada. Confira seu `php.ini`. No Windows, algo do tipo:

```
extension_dir="C:/php5/ext/"
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Em outros sistemas, algo do tipo:

```
extension_dir="/usr/lib/php/modules/"
extension=mysql.so
```

Um usuário do Windows disse que o Yii exige `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` (ou seja, "**php_pdo_mysql**", ao invés de "**php_mysql**").

É importante também lembrar de **reiniciar** o PHP e/ou Apache após fazer alterações nos arquivos de configuração.

Fontes:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/18684-cdbconnection-failed-to-open-the-db-connection-could-not-find-driver/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215727/mysql-functions-dont-load-when-using-custom-php-ini-on-windows-server

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda ... so não entendi pq não habilita automaticamente.

Answer (score 1):

O seu DSN mostra que você está tentando usar o driver do MySQL e o erro indica que o driver está indisponível.

Verifique se a extensão está instalada.

No Ubuntu/Debian pode fazer o seguinte para verificar se está instalado

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep php5-mysql
```

Caso não esteja, pode instalar assim

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Logo em seguida reinicie o apache para que as novas configurações entre em vigor.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Caso já esteja instalado verifique qual para qual host o MySQL está aceitando conexões. Execute

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Altere o `bind-address` para `0.0.0.0` para escutar conexões de qualquer IP.

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Dê permissão de conexão para todos os IPs

```
mysql -u root -p
```

No prompt do MySQL digite

```
use mysql
// Caso o root não possua senha use
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%'
// Se tiver senha use
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'senha';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

Reinicie o MySQL

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: esta instalado já